# Update links in HTML using PHP DOMDocument and DOMXPath

Tags: php, html, domdocument

So I need to update all image links in some HTML. Let's say my HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <p><a href="example-1.html">This</a> is a normal link. I don't want to change this link.</p>
            <p>But this is an image link: <a href="example-1.html"><img src="http://fpoimg.com/150"></a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to replace all image links, that is links that contain just an image, to example-2.html, using PHP's DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    $parent = $img->parentNode;
}
```

I'm not sure if it's faster to grab all of the images and then check the parent, or grab all of the links and then check the child. I think there would be more regular text links on the page than images, so I think the former would be faster.

I'm just not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

As you actually want to update `a` tags, you should try to use an XPath that leads you to those `a` tags that contain an `img` tag. This is possible with the following XPath and code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$anchor_list = $xpath->query( "//a[img[@src]]" );
foreach($anchor_list as $a) {
    $url = $a->getAttribute('href');
    // modify url ...
    $url = str_replace("this", "that", $url);
    $a->setAttribute('href', $url);
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML(  );
echo $content;
```